# .htaccess file in top directory overrides .htaccess in subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using different .htaccess files to control the website.
I have a .htaccess file in the `public_html` folder, and one in a folder called "Private".

The files were working perfectly, until I created `ErrorDocument` handlers in the top level .htaccess file. When I went to the "Private" folder, I didn't have to provide credentials...

Everything was working fine until I made the `ErrorDocument` handlers. What's the problem, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can **nullify** `ErrorDocument` directives of parent .htaccess by using these directives in `/private/.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

Comment: The private directory is still accessible without a password.

Comment: Can you post content of both .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The /Private directory is Password Protected after I deleted and added protection again...